# Hibernate JPA Template does merge updates the referenced objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My question is like I have a Customer object having a set of Locations. Now if I am making a change in the property of one or 2 of locations. I then call merge on Customer object. Does Hibernate saves the changes in location or I would have to explicitly call merge for each location. I have cascade all for locations property in Customer.  For some reasons, when I am calling merge on Customer, it is not updating Location values in DB.

Comment: Do the Location Entity override the hashCode and equals methods to be used correctly at a java Set??

Comment: Also, Check if new Locations entities are been created (the dirty ones) instead of been updated...

Comment: Hi Carlitos, it's a legacy code and I checked it does not override hashcode and equals method. However not overriding hashcode and equals method would have caused issue while making a new entry into set. As for new Location object, JVM will check its hashcode and on the basis of haschode, will decide where to put in the bucket, if there is already entry with that haschode, it will call equals method and decided if new entry needs to be made on the basis of equal method return.

Comment: But here we are making changes to an object already there in the set. I am not adding new location but changing property to an exiting object. Also I checked there is a lazy loading applied on the locations but it has already been loaded as I am able to access Locations.  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Ok... another question: the customer object is also dirty but its changes are updated at the database?? or you are just using its merge to propagate the merge event into Locations??

Comment: I am just using customer's merge to propagate the merge event into Locations. I have not checked if other attributes of the customer are being saved with that merge. In fact, method where merge is being called on customer is also a legacy method I am just utilizing it after making some changes on Location. I am sure that attributes of customer are being saved but will check and confirm. Thanks again.

Comment: If your Costumer entity is not been updated either... Check if the entityManager that does the merge inside of a given Transaction (JTA or ResourceLocal)...

Answer (score 1):

Please share your code for the Customer entity and the Location entity. That would help to understand the issue in a better way.